# Karate SDL - Pass paramters to form fields (for oauth auth) from another feature file

Tags: karate

I have the same issue. I would like to send parameters to form fields to generate oauth token based on grant type password as below.

I have two features

```
1) AuthToken.feature

Feature:Get Access token

Scenario: oauth 2 flow

Given url tokenURL 
And header Authorization = call read('this:basic-auth.js') { username: '#(clientid)', password:'#(clientsecret)' } And form field grant_type = 'password'
form field username = email
form field password = password 
And request { username: '#(email)', password: '#(password)'} 
When method post 
Then status 200
def accessToken = response.access_token

I would like to call this from other feature as below 2) 

CallingFeature.feature

Background: 
# Generate jwt for testkarateuser 
* def result = callonce read('karateUserAuthToken.feature') { clientid: '<value>', clientsecret:'<value>', email: '<value>', password: '<value>' }
```

I get the error as
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: karateUserAuthToken.feature:11 - evaluation (js) failed: email, javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "email" is not defined in at line number 1 stack trace: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470) Could you please help on this to get this resolved. */

Thanks.

Comment: I can't make out from this level of info. please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue